# How to determine, whether time series is random

Tags: time-series, forecasting, random-forest

I have a discrete time series (1000 discrete ticks), which only has values from {0,1,2,3,4}. Here's a picture of 150 somewhere in the middle of this series. But, actually, it has no sensitive difference from the other 850 ticks. I mean, the series is completely stationary and has no visible dependencies...

[image]

**Goal** is to forecast summed values within 1,3 and 10 tick intervals​.

**In my opinion**, the best approach is to take the median for 1 tick and take the average among 3-length window and 10-length windows, because I think that it's random.

**I want** to know, are there any methods that help to find out, whether a series is random or not. And listen to your ideas about forecasting it.

**Remark for Martjin's answer**:

Thank you for your answer.

1. It's more likely, that state 3 goes to state 1 or 2 than 3 just because there are more states of 1 and 2 in the sample (they are more probable in general)
2. I have thought of statistical tests, but the problem is that I have to idea of expected frequencies​. Imagine, that this time sequence, which shows number of customers per day. It may have the same values to dominate over others just because some loyal customers visit us. So it is still completely random but now uniformly random. But with assumption of frequency you will reject the Hypothesis, that claims the randomness of the series.

I thought there are some tricks with algorithms, which have inner states. EG.: If we show, that it has very bad accuracy, that will mean, that 100% confident time series is independent​ from it's previous states

Comment: the title of your post doesnt seem to match what you end up asking in it

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific about what you mean by "random." The post intimates that you are undertaking considerations of *stationarity* and perhaps *serial correlation*, but that you are unconcerned about uniformity of states or of transitions between them.  Evidently you are focusing on more subtle characteristics, but which ones, exactly? For instance, are you concerned with whether transitions appear to be independent? With stationarity of second- or higher-order moments of the multivariate distributions?

Comment: Do you want answers about "randomness testing" (question title)? Or about forecasting strategies (stated goal)?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 First, i want to know about randomness testing. Whether we decide, that it's not random, i will need a forecasting strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you generate a matrix with cells $a_{ij}$ for frequency of transfers from old position $i$ to new position $j$, then I am near-certain you will see that there is no randomness in this simple 1-step comparison.

\begin{matrix}
  a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} & a_{03} & a_{04} \\
  a_{11} & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
  a_{21} & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
  a_{31} & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
  a_{41} & a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
 \end{matrix}

Obviously the positions 1, 2, 3 are more occupied than 0 and 4. In that sense there is non-randomness. I am guessing that this type of non-randomness is not what you were looking for. However, there is also non-randomness in the sense that some positions seem to have a preference to change into other position, beyond the non-randomness in the occupation distribution.

For instance it seems that, if the the current position is 3 then it is much more likely that the next position is 1 or 2 than 3. (only on 32 occasions the position remained in the same place, although it is difficult to compare single and double steps, and that is unlikely randomness, making this data to favor change and not remain in the same position)

Using a chi-square test and expressing the variation of the observed frequencies in comparison to expected frequencies allows you to evaluate the non randomness and where it occurs. You can extend the 1-step matrix to multi-step matrices if you have more data.

If you have sufficient information and data then you can study more variational algorithms.

*P.S. Can I get a small fee for the profits that you make with your gambling on number of goals in soccer games?*

### ###############################################

### Edit 9th June evening

Based on your comments I have made an example performing the chi-squared test.

It is remarkable that the values are most predictive for 3 or 4 days later, and not so much (not at all) for 1 day later. You will have to test this with the rest of the data.

```
> # generate the data
> y<-c(2,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,0,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,
 2,2,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,2,
 2,1,0,3,1,3,4,3,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,3,1,2,2,4,3,
 1,3,4,3,3,4,3,1,4,1,2,1,1,3,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,
 2,1,1,2,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,4,3,1,
 1,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,4,0,1,1,1,4,1,3,1,3,2,2,3,
 0,4,2,2,4,3,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,1)


# m[new,old] is a matrix with observations that the old level changes into the new level
m <- matrix(rep(0,25),5)
diff <- 1 # the effect seems to be strongest for n = 3,4
for (i in 1:(length(y)-diff)) {
  old <- y[i]+1
  new <- y[(i+diff)]+1
  m[new,old] = m[new,old] + 1
}

#statistical test
chisq.test(m)

#making a table with expected values
f <- count(y)[,2]/150
transmission_expected <- as.matrix(cbind(f,f,f,f,f))
m_expected <- t(t(transmission_expected)*(f*(150-diff)))

#explorative information to see which values stand out the most
(m-m_expected)^2/m_expected
m
m_expected


n <- matrix(rep(0,5^3),5)
colnames(n) <-c("0-0","0-1","0-2","0-3","0-4",
                "1-0","1-1","1-2","1-3","1-4",
                "2-0","2-1","2-2","2-3","2-4",
                "3-0","3-1","3-2","3-3","3-4",
                "4-0","4-1","4-2","4-3","4-4")
rownames(n) <-c("0","1","2","3","4")
diff <- 1
for (i in 2:(length(y)-diff)) {
  old <- y[i-1]*5+y[i]+1
  new <- y[i+diff]+1
  n[new,old] = n[new,old] + 1
}
chisq.test(n[,-c(1,25)])

n_expected <- matrix(rep(f,25),5)*colSums(n)
colnames(n_expected) <-c("0-0","0-1","0-2","0-3","0-4",
                "1-0","1-1","1-2","1-3","1-4",
                "2-0","2-1","2-2","2-3","2-4",
                "3-0","3-1","3-2","3-3","3-4",
                "4-0","4-1","4-2","4-3","4-4")
rownames(n_expected) <-c("0","1","2","3","4")

round((n-n_expected)^2/n_expected,3)
n
round(n_expected,1)
```

### ###############################################

### Edit Output

frequencies

```
> f
[1] 0.02666667 0.34000000 0.34666667 0.22000000 0.06666667
```

Expected transitions based on frequencies (the total is 150). Old value in columns and new value in rows

```
> round(m_expected,1)
       f    f    f    f   f
[1,] 0.1  1.4  1.4  0.9 0.3
[2,] 1.4 17.2 17.6 11.1 3.4
[3,] 1.4 17.6 17.9 11.4 3.4
[4,] 0.9 11.1 11.4  7.2 2.2
[5,] 0.3  3.4  3.4  2.2 0.7
```

observed transitions in 1 day

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1   18   18   12    2
[3,]    1   19   19   11    1
[4,]    1    9   11    6    6
[5,]    1    3    3    3    0
```

observed transitions in 2 days

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    4    0    0
[2,]    2   17   15   12    5
[3,]    2   19   17   10    3
[4,]    0   11   12    7    2
[5,]    0    3    4    3    0
```

observed transitions in 3 days

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    3    0    0
[2,]    1   19   17    9    5
[3,]    1   17   13   18    1
[4,]    2   10   16    3    1
[5,]    0    3    2    2    3
```

observed transitions in 4 days

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    2    0
[2,]    1   18   23    6    3
[3,]    0   16   17   13    3
[4,]    0   15    7    7    3
[5,]    3    0    2    4    1
```

The tables already show an obvious increase away from the expected values without a need to perform quantitative checks. Quantitative checks: the chi-squared test confirms this with p = 0.0355 for 3 days and p = 0.000132, meaning that these results are unlikely to occur by chance.

The most unlikely non-random effect is that after being in position 0 (which occured 4 times), it is is very likely to be in position 4 exactly after four days (75% out of the 4), while the presence in position 4 is only 7%.

Limits:
1) they were my 3th and 4th check of the data which means I was squeezing out the possibility to see an effect and you'd have to confirm it with new data (even though the low p-values would hold in a correction for multiple comparisons, anyways the sequence is suspected to be non-random).
2) The chi-square test assumes Gaussian distributions for the data. You could devise a test analyzing the chances by using binomial distributions, although easier would be to just check the results with more data, which you seem to have.

Comment: I added a remark for your answer in my question

Comment: For frequencies of the levels, $f_i$, with $\sum f_i = 1$. You expect the cells on the diagonal to be $a_{ii}=f_i^2$ (horizontal pieces in the graph). I'm counting $a_{33} \sim 6/150$ and $f_3 \sim 26/150$. So you are right with 6 times the event is actually occurring *more* often than what is likely. On the other hand the sum of the diagonal is close to 32/150 which seems to be lower than expected. If you provide the numbers in a table than it would be easier to provide a demonstration. A simple description of the patterns seems possible. Otherwise use tools such as http://fourmilab.ch/random

Comment: Sorry, for not being active for so long, but, could you please explain how you generate the expected values? I'm not familiar with R

Comment: Also, could you please detail, how did you notice, that  "It is remarkable that the values are most predictive for 3 or 4 days later, and not so much (not at all) for 1 day later"

Comment: I will add the output of the script. What the script does is finding out 1) the frequencies that the different levels occur. 2) How often a switch from level $i$ to level $j$ occurs after $x$ days. 3) Whether this change is peculiar (using a chi-square tests, which may be improved upon since it assumes a normal distribution while it is a more precisely binomial distribution that only approaches a normal distribution for larger numbers). 4) a view in a table to see where the differences occur.

Comment: Aahaha, that's not soccer game))))

Answer (score 0):

check out this study: https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03209475

There are a dozen indices to quantify "randomness" of the number sequence.

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.